# Show that $ y = 3\cos 4x + 4 \sin 4x$ can be rewritten in the form $y = A \cos \left( 4x + \varphi \right)$. Also, find $ A $ and $ \varphi $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am asked the following problem:

> Show that $ y = 3\cos 4x + 4 \sin 4x$ can be rewritten in the form $y = A \cos \left( 4x + \varphi  \right)$. Also, find $ A $ and $ \varphi $.

This was taken from a second degree differential equations' exercise sheet, but it seems out of place.

I honestly have no idea where to start, it's basically making no sense to me. I will be thankful if someone can shine a light on the path to be followed, so I can work the exercise.

**Textbook's answer:** $\varphi = \arctan \left( - \dfrac{4}{3} \right)$

Thank you.

Comment: @Renan thank you, only by your edit (which was actually wrong on the textbook) I could solve it. Best Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice the both sine and cosine have the same argument ($4x$). You can then use
$$ A\cos(ax+b)=A\cos(ax)\cos(b)-A\sin(b)\sin(ax) $$

Then, relating to your problem, $a=4$, and you have a system for $A$ and $b=\varphi$, in which
$$
\begin{cases}
   A\cos(\varphi)=3\\
   A\sin(\varphi)=-4\\
\end{cases}
$$

The answer is trivial, divinding the second equation by the first:
$$
\tan\varphi = -\frac{4}{3}\Rightarrow \varphi=\arctan\left(-\frac{4}{3}\right)
$$

Considering $\varphi\in [-\frac{\pi}{2};\frac{\pi}{2}]$.

Comment: You should explain why φ is not $\arctan\Bigl(-\frac43\Bigr)+\pi$.

Comment: $\varphi=\arctan\left(\frac{-4}{3}\right)+n\pi, n\in\mathcal{Z}$, actually, but I'll edit the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: this can be made to look like the $\cos$ angle addition formula

$$cos(\alpha + \beta) = \cos \alpha \cos \beta - \sin \alpha \sin \beta$$

by (recognizing the pythagorean triangle hidden in there, and) rewriting it as

$$y = 5 \cdot ( \frac{3}{5} \cos 4x - \frac{-4}{5} \sin 4x)$$

Now, find an angle $\phi$ so that $cos \phi = \frac{3}{5}$ and $\sin \phi = \frac{-4}{5}$.

Answer (score 0):

By the rules of cosine of a sum of two angles,

$$
A \cos (\theta + \varphi) = A \cos \theta \cos \varphi - A \sin \theta \sin \varphi
$$
Matching terms in $\cos \theta$ and terms in $\sin \theta$ to your given expression, you have
$$
A \cos \varphi (\cos \theta) = 3 (\cos\theta) \\
-A \sin \varphi (\sin\theta) = 4  (\sin\theta)
$$
Dividing the second of these equations by the first, and cancelling out the $\tan \theta$ that appears on both sides of the resulting equation, gives
$$
-A \tan \varphi = \frac43
$$
Now to find $a$ (which you should instinctively gues will be $\sqrt{3^2+4^2} = \pm5$):

Insert some particular value for $\theta$ (which is  $4x$ in your expressions).  Zero is a nice value.
$$
A \cos \left( 0 -\tan^{-1}\frac43 \right)= 3\cos(0)=3
$$
Since $\sec^2 = \tan^2 +1$, $\cos \left( 0 -\tan^{-1}\frac43 \right) = \frac35$. THus $A=5$.

Answer (score 0):

The forms are identical trigonometrically, although in differing external form.

Confirmation by differential equation is some sort of acid test by setting up differential equation for both to check same result. Otherwise no relevance to this tag.

$$ y^{\prime  \prime} + 16 x =0 $$

The boundary conditions to integrate should then necessarily use the given $\varphi,$ as phase difference which we can find by dividing by $5$ etc..